# findAllById() returns all equivalent records

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I implemented the function as "select * from stat where id = ?" with Spring Boot;
JPA method findAllById(), but it returns all equivalent records.
Please show me how I should fix the code.

```sql
create table stat(
    id integer
    , row integer
    , col integer
    , data double precision not null
    , constraint stat_pk1 primary key (id, row, col)
)
```

```sh
otnj=# select * from stat;
id | row | col | data
----+------+-----+----------
1 | 1964 | 1 | 352832
1 | 1965 | 1 | 366649
1 | 1966 | 1 | 432937
...
1 | 2020 | 1 | 4115828
1 | 2021 | 1 | 173263
(58 rows)
```

```java
package com.sct.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class StatId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1289075301160465252L;

        @Column(name = "id")
        private Integer id;

        public StatId() {
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
                return Objects.hash(id);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (this == obj)
                        return true;
                if (obj == null)
                        return false;
                if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                        return false;
                StatId other = (StatId) obj;
                return Objects.equals(id, other.id);
        }

        public Integer getId() {
                return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
                this.id = id;
        }
}
```

```java
package com.sct.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="stat")
public class StatCell implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6501935237628672264L;

        @EmbeddedId
        private StatId id;

        @Column(name = "row")
        private Integer row;

        @Column(name = "col")
        private Integer col;

        @Column(name = "data")
        private Double data;

        public StatCell() {
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
                return Objects.hash(col, data, id, row);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (this == obj)
                        return true;
                if (obj == null)
                        return false;
                if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                        return false;
                StatCell other = (StatCell) obj;
                return Objects.equals(col, other.col) && Objects.equals(data, other.data) && Objects.equals(id, other.id)
                                && Objects.equals(row, other.row);
        }
// getters and setters
}
```

```java
package com.sct.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.sct.entity.StatCell;
import com.sct.entity.StatId;

@Repository
public interface StatCellRepository extends JpaRepository<StatCell, StatId> {
        List<StatCell> findAll();

        @Query(value="SELECT s FROM StatCell s WHERE id = ?1")
        List<StatCell> findAllById(@Param("id") Iterable<StatId> ids);
}
```

```java
package com.sct.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.sct.entity.StatCell;
import com.sct.entity.StatCellId;
import com.sct.entity.StatId;
import com.sct.repository.StatCellRepository;

@Service
public class StatService {
        protected static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StatService.class);

        @Autowired(required=true)
        private StatCellRepository repo;

        public List<StatCell> findAllById(Integer id) {
                StatId statId = new StatId();
                statId.setId(id);
                List<StatId> statIds = new ArrayList<>();
                statIds.add(statId);

                List<StatCell> cells = repo.findAllById(statIds);
                log.info("cells={}", cells.size());

                return cells;
        }

        public Map<StatCellId, Double> findByIdAsMap(Integer id) {
                Map<StatCellId, Double> map = new HashMap<>();

                for (StatCell cell : findAllById(id)) {
                        StatCellId cellId = new StatCellId();
                        cellId.setId(id);
                        cellId.setCol(cell.getCol());
                        cellId.setRow(cell.getRow());

                        Double data = cell.getData();
                        log.info("col={}, row={}, data={}, hashCode={}",
                                        cell.getCol(), cell.getRow(), data, cellId.hashCode());

                        map.put(cellId, data);
                }

                log.info("map.size={}", map.size());
                return map;
        }
}
```

```
2021-12-22 02:32:08.663 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
    select
        statcell0_.id as id1_0_,
        statcell0_.col as col2_0_,
        statcell0_.data as data3_0_,
        statcell0_.row as row4_0_ 
    from
        stat statcell0_ 
    where
        statcell0_.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        statcell0_.id as id1_0_,
        statcell0_.col as col2_0_,
        statcell0_.data as data3_0_,
        statcell0_.row as row4_0_ 
    from
        stat statcell0_ 
    where
        statcell0_.id=?
2021-12-22 02:32:08.663 TRACE 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2021-12-22 02:32:08.665 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 0
2021-12-22 02:32:08.666 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.sct.entity.StatCell#component[id]{id=1}]
2021-12-22 02:32:08.671 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 1
2021-12-22 02:32:08.671 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.sct.entity.StatCell#component[id]{id=1}]
...
2021-12-22 02:32:08.675 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 56
2021-12-22 02:32:08.675 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.sct.entity.StatCell#component[id]{id=1}]
2021-12-22 02:32:08.675 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result set row: 57
2021-12-22 02:32:08.675 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] org.hibernate.loader.Loader              : Result row: EntityKey[com.sct.entity.StatCell#component[id]{id=1}]
2021-12-22 02:32:08.676 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Resolving attributes for [com.sct.entity.StatCell#component[id]{id=1}]
2021-12-22 02:32:08.676 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `col` : value = 1
2021-12-22 02:32:08.676 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`col`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2021-12-22 02:32:08.676 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `data` : value = 352832.0
2021-12-22 02:32:08.676 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`data`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2021-12-22 02:32:08.676 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Processing attribute `row` : value = 1964
2021-12-22 02:32:08.676 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Attribute (`row`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
2021-12-22 02:32:08.677 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad         : Done materializing entity [com.sct.entity.StatCell#component[id]{id=1}]
2021-12-22 02:32:08.677 DEBUG 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl         : committing
2021-12-22 02:32:08.678  INFO 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] com.sct.service.StatService              : cells=58
2021-12-22 02:32:08.679  INFO 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] com.sct.service.StatService              : col=1, row=1964, data=352832.0, hashCode=32747
2021-12-22 02:32:08.679  INFO 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] com.sct.service.StatService              : col=1, row=1964, data=352832.0, hashCode=32747
2021-12-22 02:32:08.679  INFO 37572 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] com.sct.service.StatService              : col=1, row=1964, data=352832.0, hashCode=32747
```

In interface StatCellRepository, whether I omit @Query or not, Iterable<> or not, the result: every record (col, row, data) is always same.
What happens on earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get different values, you need:

1. move the attributes "row" and "col" from StatCell to StatId and change the equals and hashcode methods in these entities;
2. in the repository use method like this:

`List findAllByIdId(Integer id);`

I think you get the same values because entity StatId only contains "id". This means that only one row should have a unique value "id". If  you have used a constraint key for the table(id, row, col), then you must use all  the key attributes in your EmbaddedId.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I moved row and col from StatCell to StatId and changed the methods.And I changed the logic to get the one or zero record once and to repeatedly call this method instead of getting all the records (id=?) once from the repo because StatCell couldn't determine the uniq record.
`@Query("SELECT s FROM StatCell s WHERE id=?1.id AND col=?1.col AND row=?1.row")
Optional<StatCell> getByIdOrColOrRow(@Param("id") StatId id);`
But STS reports an error.It seems to be a bad parameterized query.
`hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker  unexpected token: 1.antlr.NoViableAltException`

Comment: In this code, I am not using @Query annotation, only methods without annotation. In the first case, you can get the rows by Id, in the second - row by the constraint key. 


`List<StatCell> findAllByIdId(Integer id);

Optional<StatCell> findByIdIdAndIdRowAndIdCol(Integer id, Integer rowId, Integer colId);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! Your findByIdIdAndIdRowAndIdCol() without @Query returns the result I've expected.